# How does InstallShield add a program to the "recetly added" list

Tags: windows-installer

When I run the Setup.exe created by InstallShield it does not add the newly installed program to the "recently added" list.  Am I missing a setting somewhere?

Comment: Do you mean in the start menu? The shortcuts?

Comment: Yes - once I found you had to specifically set up shortcuts all became clear.  Many thanks for responding.